# GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to stream data to the browser. I'm struggling, however, to connect it to the browser. Here's my html:

```
<ul class="tweets"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var tweetList = $('ul.tweets');
        socket.on('tweet', function (data) {
            tweetList .prepend('<li>' + data.user + ': ' + data.text + '</li>'); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

And here's the relevant parts of my app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
    , twitter = require('ntwitter')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html'); });

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

io.sockets.volatile.emit('tweets', {
            user: data.user.screen_name,
            text: data.text,
            geo : geo,
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
                });
```

I installed socket.io 0.9.16 via my packages.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.2.6",
    "jade": "*",
    "ntwitter":"0.2.10",
    "socket.io":"0.9.x"
  }
```

Can anyone help me out here? Why can't it find the file?

Digging a bit deeper. To test the socket, I put this in the app.js:

```
var socket = io.listen(app);
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Manager> has no method 'listen'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andy/dev/node/mytwittermap/app.js:49:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I guess, you will have to instantiate the socket.io server.

Comment: Great - that now seems to be working (lots of good debug info in console). Now onto why it's not displaying in the browser. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 100):

Your setup needs to look something like this:

```
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
...
server.listen(app.get('port')); // not 'app.listen'!
```

Comment: Thanks, your line: "// not 'app.listen'! " Helped a lot !!

Comment: Thanks for the "not app.listen"

Comment: 2016 here. I had the same error. Details have changed, but the part that we need to do `server.listen` (not on app) is still valid. Thanks!

Comment: @sra Can you have a look at this I just posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659396/socket-io-webrtc-nodejs-video-chat-app-getting-errors-over-https-err-ssl-prot

Comment: (socket.io).listen is not working, had to type (socket.io)(server) directly

Comment: `app.get('port')` didn't work for me, but `process.env.PORT || 3000` did

Answer (score 11):

- You need to instantiate the socket.io connection and
- You need to use `server.listen()` and not `app.listen()`

Try something like this:

```
// at the top of app.js
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// your code

// at the bottom of app.js
server.listen('3000', () => {
  console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
})
```